# How to add a database user to config.php

Tags: php, joomla, config

I am a self taught web developer so excuse my lack of skill when it comes to the more complicated issues. 
I am running joomla 3.6.5 and PHP 4.0.10.18
I recently changed domains and can no longer access the administrator of Joomla. 
I get this error when I try to log in. 
"Not Found
The requested URL /administrator/index.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I believe I have it narrowed down to a problem with the congig.php file. 
The user and password that I normally use to log in is not in the config.php file.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. 
Also if I can post anything more to help let me know. I'm not sure if it's safe to post my config.php file. 
Many thanks!

Comment: the file is not there, thats the issue.

Comment: PHP _4_, really?

Comment: @Don'tPanic has to be a typo, that version of joomla requires 5.3.10+, unless the joomla version is a typo

Answer (score 1):

The user and password you use to login are stored (securely) in the database.

The configuration.php contains the host, database name, login and password relative to the database access.

Your error means something different though: it could be that you have moved your web root, you placed an .htaccess that routes the admin wrongly (possibly in an attempt to protect it from unauthorised access), so first of all ensure your web root is there where it should be:

For example, add a comment line to your robots.txt (such as

```
#comment
```

at the very end), then load it through your browser: http://example.com/robots.txt

**Can you see the line?**

- **No**: You think your webroot is where your robots.txt is, but it's not.
- **Yes**: Is the administrator folder there?

  - **No**: Extract the Joomla Upgrade package over this folder and possibly it could start working.
  - **Yes**: Rename the .htaccess file to something else, possibly it's its fault

Not solved yet? Contact your hosting provider or read their howtos

Comment: Thank you Riccardo.
I did your suggestions and YES I could see the comment added to robots.txt
The configuration.php file and the administrator folder are there. 
The .htaccess file was named .htaccess.old - I changed it and still have the same problem. 
The website was moved from one domain to another by Go Daddy. I have exhausted their ability to help and I am really stuck. 
The website is functioning fine I just can't log in to the administrator since the move.